# How to change Button Image when ListView is empty through a trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, datatrigger, wpf-style

I would like to change the image of an WPF `Button` on `ListView` empty, but I don't now which is the property I must set from the trigger.

```
<Style x:Key="DisableOnEmptyLvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <!-- which button property I must set here? -->
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Button Style="{StaticResource DisableOnEmptyLvStyle}">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource myImage}"/>
</Button>
```

Once `ListView` has items, then the image must change to the normal one.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never set the `Content` directly using a `Style`, simply because the `Style` is instantiated once and potentially reused across multiple controls. The issue is that the value that you assign in the `Setter` for `Content` is also instantiated once and *shared*, but a control can only have a single parent in WPF.

What can go wrong? If you set or change the `Content` in a style and reference it for e.g. multiple `Button`s you will see that only the last button shows the image. The first button gets its image set as `Content`, then the next button sets the image as `Content` and effectively removes the content of the first button.

There are two options that you can consider.

1. Create the images as resources and force each reference in XAML to get a new instance of the image by setting the [`x:Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xshared-attribute) attribute to `False`.

   > When set to `false`, modifies WPF resource-retrieval behavior so that requests for the attributed resource create a new instance for each request instead of sharing the same instance for all requests.

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
      <!-- ...your image sources for "myImage" and "myImage". -->

      <Image x:Key="myImageConrol" x:Shared="False"  Source="{StaticResource myImage}"/>
      <Image x:Key="myOtherImageConrol" x:Shared="False" Source="{StaticResource myImage}"/>

      <Style x:Key="DisableOnEmptyLvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource myImageConrol}"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
               <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource myOtherImageConrol}">
               </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Window.Resources>
   ```

   ```
   <Button Style="{StaticResource DisableOnEmptyLvStyle}"/>
   ```
2. Create data templates and swap them out. This works because - as the name says - they are templates and its controls will be instantiated for each control they are applied to.

   ```
   <Style x:Key="DisableOnEmptyLvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
         <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Image Source="{StaticResource myImage}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <Image Source="{StaticResource myOtherImage}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
   ```

   ```
   <Button Style="{StaticResource DisableOnEmptyLvStyle}"/>
   ```

Comment: Your solutions are great! I also must say that it also works by setting Template property with the correct image source within the DataTrigger.

Comment: @Ralph Thank you :-) . Yes, but usually the intention and consequences are different. A `DataTemplate` is a way to express the appearance of a data item, it does not affect how the hosting control itself is styled or how it behaves. It is usual to swap data templates. A control template on the other hand changes the appearance of the control and often how it behaves, since part of the structure is constrained by required parts and named parts. It is rather unusual to exchange a control template "on the fly". The impact is much larger.

Comment: @Ralph So in general I recommend using data templates. If it is not about changing the appearance, but structurally extending a control there is also an option to create a custom control.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following:

```
<Style x:Key="DisableOnEmptyLvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Content">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource myImageAtLeastOne}"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Image Source="{StaticResource myImageEmpty}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Button Style="{StaticResource DisableOnEmptyLvStyle}" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).